# How can I replace the standard Android dialler

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to intercept incoming calls android 2.3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180727/how-to-intercept-incoming-calls-android-2-3-x)

I am making an app that overrides the default telephone screen and I it need to be compatible with Android 2.3 onwards.

Currently I have this code:

```
private void answerCallAidl() throws RemoteException {
    // telephonyService.silenceRinger();       -------not work on 2.3
    // telephonyService.answerRingingCall();   -------not work on 2.3

    Intent headSetUnPluggedintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
    headSetUnPluggedintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY);
    headSetUnPluggedintent.putExtra("state", 1); // 0 = unplugged  1 = Headset with microphone 2 = Headset without microphone
    headSetUnPluggedintent.putExtra("name", "Headset");

    // TODO: Should we require a permission?
    sendOrderedBroadcast(headSetUnPluggedintent, null);

    Intent buttonDown = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);           
    buttonDown.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                          KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
    sendOrderedBroadcast(buttonDown, "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");

    // froyo and beyond trigger on buttonUp instead of buttonDown
    Intent buttonUp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);             
    buttonUp.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP,
                           KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
    sendOrderedBroadcast(buttonUp, "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");
} 


private void ignoreCallAidl() throws RemoteException {
    // telephonyService.silenceRinger();     -------not work on 2.3
    // telephonyService.endCall();           -------not work on 2.3
    Intent buttonUp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);             
    buttonUp.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                        KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
    sendOrderedBroadcast(buttonUp, "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");
}
```

My problems are:

1. I am unable to reject incoming calls.
2. It does not work on version 2.3.5.
3. I want my app to replace the default telephone screen.

I would appreciate very much any help.

Comment: Who the hell wants an app on a phone that rejects incoming calls?

Comment: the user can click on button that rejects the incoming call

Answer (score 0):

In simple word - it is not possible.

Previously there was a cheat in JAVA (using reflection) but now its no more available. Please refer below,

```
Class c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
m.setAccessible(true);
telephonyService = (ITelephony)m.invoke(tm);
```

You should refer [this](http://blog.wangling.me/2009/08/why-it-is-impossible-to-intercept-incoming-calls-on-android/) link; which tells that it is not possible. I would suggest to give up this idea soon after reading this.

Comment: it is not work on android 2.3.3

Comment: it is working on few devices only. I am not aware for which all version it will work. Purpose of my detailing is to convey that there were few ways but nothing concrete to deal with this use case.