# Intercepting call in Android

Tags: android

I want to intercept incoming call in android.
One way is to extend "BroadcastReceiver". Is there any other way?

Also, does "BroadcastReceiver" works on all andorid versions? See this link - [How to intercept incoming calls android 2.3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180727/how-to-intercept-incoming-calls-android-2-3-x)

Answer (score 1):

Yes Broadcast Receiver works in all versions. Please refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html. It is available since version 1 (i.e. from the start of Android).

I used PhoneStateListener (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html) . It is also available since version 1.